# Is it possible to track different countries in google analytics with the same domain?

Tags: google-analytics

Currently my site `example.com` is tracking sales from the UK.

Can I create another instance in Google Analytics in order to track all the users from Europe without creating a subdomain like `example.com/eu`

Is this possible?

Comment: Technically `example.com/eu` is not a subdomain, it is path `/eu` on hostname `example.com`.  A subdomain would have been `eu.example.com`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you are attempting to view purchases by origin country - Google Analytics provides this functionality with [Advanced Segments](http://www.markcregan.com/advanced-segments-in-google-analytics-examples/) so, unless you need to track "site.co.uk" or "site.eu" domains, your existing configuration should already have this information.

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced segments as Danlefree mentioned are the easiest method. It sounded from your question like you're wanting to separate them into a different profile, if for some reason that is the case you can do this by creating an additional profile and using the filter to filter out all visits that are not from Europe.